# Forcibly stop subsequent scripts executing on a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to write some JavaScript that stops any subsequent scripts from running.

The specific case for this is a chrome extension: I'm injecting a content script at [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at), which will be run in the page before any other scripts, and will potentially redirect the page to somewhere else before the page loads.

Currently other subsequent scripts are interfering with the redirect I'm injecting, so that the redirect doesn't happen, I think because their scripts are also doing subsequent redirects themselves (although I'm not 100% sure). I'd like to just stop any other scripts running after my script at all, so I can be confident my redirect will actually work.

A specific example:

```
<script>
  // What do I need to put here to stop 'hi' appearing?
</script>
<script>
  alert('hi');
</script>
```

Some things that don't work:

- Emptying every script tag's content: http://jsfiddle.net/zL9h51ng/
- Deleting every other script tag: http://jsfiddle.net/wu14hgx4/

Comment: Have you tried removing everything inside script tags other than yours?

Comment: Yep, doesn't work. Some failing jsfiddles added above.

Comment: You are misunderstanding that as soon as browser encounters script tag it executes it. There is no way to prevent this using other javascript. By the time your javascript runs it's either too late or the other script tags don't exist yet and there is nothing you can do with a tag that doesn't yet exist

Comment: Any links to exactly how the browser does find and execute scripts in this case?

Comment: can easily google how browsers process a page.

Comment: If you put a script tag in the head and try to log `document.documentElement.innerHTML`, you can see how it cuts off right at the script tag.

Comment: You could handle script requests with chrome.webRequest. No clue about the inline scripts, though, since you cannot modify the body of a request..

Comment: What if you use `window.onbeforeunload` to prevent other location changes?